# how to dynamically fetch data from database in autocomplete textbox

Tags: php, jquery, html

Can anyone help me in fetching data from the database while typing in `autocomplete` textbox?

### HTML Code

```
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" name="autocomplete" class="autocomplete">
<label for="autocomplete">Test Section</label>enter code here
```

### jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: {
               $sql="SELECT * FROM test_section";
               if($r=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
                   while($result= $r->fetch_row()){
               ?> 
            "<?php echo result['Test_main_sections']?>":null,
            "English Language": null,
            "Quantitative Aptitude": null,
            "Reasoning Ability": null,
        <?php }}?>
        }
    });
});
```

Well, i have tried fetching data using PHP query but it is not working!

Comment: So you added php code to your javascript?

Comment: What PHP query did you try?

Comment: I would suggest reading the rest of the manual for whatever plugin you are using

Answer (score 0):

This is something I have done in the past and works quite well for me:

Please note that I have used Bootstrap in my project and used the typehead BS version. Hope this might be of any help.

The input field below.

`<input type="text" id="globalSearch" class="form-control input-sm typeahead" placeholder="Search..." data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off">`

```
/* Start Search */
    var $input = $('#globalSearch');
    $input.typeahead({
        autoSelect: true,
        minLength: 3,
        items: 20,
        delay: 500,
        highlight: true,
        displayKey: 'StoreName',
        source: function (query, process) {
            return $.getJSON('_Ajax/Search_Stores', { Search: query },
/*This search stores page will have to return json data. As user types, you can grab the 'Search' param on the page and pass that value to your DB to get the results. */
                function (data) {
                    GUID = {};
                    Profile = {};
                    userLabels = [];
                    //build results dropdown
                    $.each(data, function () {
                        var StoreName = this.StoreName
                        var Search
                        if (this.Search) {
                            Search = " (" + this.Search + ")";
                        } else {
                            Search = "";
                        }
                        userLabels.push(this.StoreName + Search);
                        GUID[this.StoreName + Search] = this.GUID;
                        Profile[this.StoreName + Search] = this.Profile;
                    });
                    process(userLabels);
                });
        },
        highlighter: function (item) {
            var StoreName = item;
            var query = this.query.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
            //Highlight search text
            return item.replace(new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig'), function ($1, match) {
                return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>'
            });
        },
        updater: function (item) {
            console.warn(item);
        }
    });

    //When search is clicked, process search again.
    $(document).on("click", "input.typeahead", function () {
        $(this).trigger("input");
    });
```

Comment: Sir am using materialize css

Comment: Maybe try this: twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples